# issue with master and slave ldap configuration

Tags: ldap, openldap

I am configuring master and slave ldap configuration.

Initially I installed LDAP in Master machine and also installed on slave machine

```
   apt-get install -y slapd ldap-utils
```

while installing LDAP in master machine I configured master ldap with the details as follows:

master details

```
ubuntu.somedc.local
domain somedc.local
dc=somedc,dc=local
```

slave details

```
slave.mysomedc.local
domain mysomedc.local
dc=mysomedc,dc=local
```

In master machine i configured slave configuration inside slapd.conf file
This is the configuration that was made in slapd.conf file of master machine

```
        replica uri=ldap://ldaptest.somedc.local:389
        binddn="cn=somecommonname,dc=somedc,dc=local"
        bindmethod=simple credentials=********

        replogfile      /var/lib/ldap/replog
```

here ldaptest.somecommonname.local is my slave machine fqdn ,389 is ldap port
now i restart the replica server's slapd process i.e of ,master

```
/etc/init.d/slapd restart
```

In slave machine i configured master configuration inside slapd.conf file
This is the configuration that was made in slapd.conf file of slave machine

```
updatedn cn=somecommonname,dc=somedc,dc=local
updateref ldap://ubuntu.somedc.local
```

here ubuntu.somedc.local is my fqdn in master server

After doing configuration i am adding users in master ldap server by using following method and expecting these users replication in slave 
ldap server but the users are not showing in slave configuration.

level1.ldif file

```
        dn: cn=somecommonname,dc=somedc,dc=local
        objectClass: inetOrgPerson
        objectClass: posixAccount
        cn: somecommonname
        givenName: somename
        sn: office
        uid: someuid
        uidNumber: 14000
        gidNumber: 14000
        homedirectory: false
        userPassword: ********
```

as like that above format i created so many users and i add those users to ldap using ldapadd

```
ldapadd -x -D cn=admin,dc=somedc,dc=local -W -f level1.ldif
```

Even i am not able to do replication

To do replication i exported the master's database

```
slapcat -l level1.ldif
```

then I copied the content to slave server using scp command, copying then if users modified in master automatically changed in slave.

```
  scp -r filename slave ip:root/
```

adding this to the slave machine.

I am not sure whether I am following correct procedure or not. If this procedure is not correct then please guide me to follow correct procedure.

Comment: What have you read to ascertain the correctness of the steps you've done so far?

Comment: i read so many ..and i use google search for master and slave configuration and ubuntu.com ,and other sites.. and with those i wrote it as my own..

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're attempting to use `slapd.conf` and `slurpd`.

`slapd.conf` is depriciated and you ought to be using [slapd.d](http://www.openldap.org/software/man.cgi?query=slapd-config&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=OpenLDAP%202.4-Release&format=html).

However, your main problem is that you're trying to use `slurpd`, which was completely removed in OpenLDAP 2.4. You should instead setup a [`syncrepl provider`](http://www.openldap.org/doc/admin24/replication.html#Syncrepl) on your master server, and a `syncrepl consumer` on your "slave" (replica) server.

Comment: ah.. i saw that slurpd..and i'm not using syncrepl..i thought that there is a simple for using slapd.conf file. in slapd.conf file i changed, as above i mentioned in both master and slave machines..